# Prove by induction that for a graph $G=(V, E)$, if it doesn't contain a cycle, then $|E|\leq|V|-1$.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, induction, trees

I want to prove the following statement using *mathematical induction*. (This problem appears in an assignment about mathematical induction.)

> For every graph $G=(V,E)$, if it doesn't contain a cycle, then $|E|\leq|V|-1$.

I know that the inequality holds when $G$ is a *tree*. I'm struggling to find an induction proof of this statement. I assume that we'll use induction on the number of vertices of $G$, i.e., $|V|$. Below is my attempt.

- *Base case*: When $|V|=1$, $|E|=0$, and the inequality holds. Hence the statement is true when $|V|=1$.
- *Induction step*: Let $k\geq1$ be a given integer. Suppose the statement holds for graphs with $|V|=k$.

This is where I got stuck. I don't know how to utilize the induction hypothesis and complete the induction step. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a connected graph with $k+1$ vertices and no cycles (so, a tree) and delete one vertex. You now have a forest with $k$ vertices. Each tree in this forest satisfies the inductive hypothesis (depending on how you've defined induction, you might need to use strong induction here). Apply the hypothesis and "reassemble" the original graph (you have to add back some edges - how many?). For an alternate approach, argue that every tree has a vertex of degree 1. If you delete that vertex, you have a tree with one vertex less. You then have to apply that to the general case of a forest.

Comment: Note that if you can prove the theorem for each connected component of your graph, or equivalently, assume without loss of generality that $G$ is connected. Recall that the sum of the degrees of all $|V|$ vertices in $G$ is $2|E|\le2(|V|-1)$ (think about grouping ends of edges in two ways, by edge vs. by vertex), so the average degree of the graph is $\le2(|V|-1)/|V|<2$, and therefore, some vertex has degree $1$. Now delete that vertex and the $1$ edge incident with it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's continue the mathematical induction based on the number of vertices: Assuming that the proposition holds for a graph with $k$ vertices. Now, suppose $G$ is a graph with $k+1$ vertices. Then $G$ must have a vertex of degree 1, denoted by $v$. Otherwise, $\delta(G) \geq 2$ implies that $G$ must contain a cycle (which can be proven by considering the longest path in $G$).

Now, let $G' = G - v$. By the induction hypothesis, we have
$$
|E(G')| \leq |V(G')| - 1. 
$$
Then,
$$
|E(G)| = |E(G')| + 1 \leq (|V(G')| - 1) + 1 = |V(G)| - 1.
$$
This completes the proof.
\qed